# Naked Domain Forwarding Broken on Godaddy with Period Slash

Tags: domain-name-system, godaddy, ip-forwarding

Is Godaddy naked domain forwarding broken when you have a `./` in the URL?

I use GoDaddy for DNS and have naked domain forwarding setup. I have my A record @ set to GoDaddy servers, and use their interface to forward all naked domain traffic to `www.`. This works fine in almost all circumstances, such as:

- Working: `example.com --> www.example.com`
- Working: `example.com/foo --> www.example.com/foo`
- Working: `example.com/123/foo --> www.example.com/123/foo`
- Working: `example.com/.foo/ --> www.example.com/.foo/`

However, when I use a period and then a slash in the naked domain name, forwarding does not work:

- Broken: `example.com/foo./`

Notice that the last working example above differs with the broken example only by the placement of the period.

When I go to the broken URL, instead of being forwarded to the `www.` page, I get the error message depicted in the screenshot below.  This is an aspx .net error message.  None of my servers use aspx or .net, so I know that this request has not even hit my server. Is this a bug with GoDaddy forwarding?

[image: server error]

Comment: It certainly looks broken. What did GoDaddy tell you when you contacted them?

Comment: They said it was a problem with my servers, even after explaining to them all of the above (including that I do not run aspx). They were very friendly, but did not seem knowledgeable about this at all. They suggested I sign up for GoDaddy hosting.

Comment: I think you need a new provider.

Comment: To further drive home my point, take a look at http://godaddy.com/.foo/ and then look at http://godaddy.com/foo./